# Finding a class and adding it to another element

Tags: class, find, addclass

I need to find a way to the get the class from a li and then add that class to a div that wraps all my main content. so...

`<div class="structBody">`
    `<ul id="ContentBreadCrumbsColor">`
      `<li class="teal"></li>`
    `</ul>`

```
  <div class="cntrWrap LI_CLASS_GOES_HERE">
    HTML TEXT GOES HERE
  </div>
```

`</div>`

Can anyone help? I have tried so many different ideas but I'm still very new to jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('div.structBody').addClass($('li.teal').attr('class'));
        }
);
```

I'd recommend the [official jQuery website's documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/), if you haven't already gone through it.

Comment: Thank you that did work but the only problem is if the li has a class of blue it still adds teal. I need it to add whatever class the li has. The li class is different on every page.

Comment: Do you have more than one li on each page? If not, you can remove `.teal` from the above code.

Comment: Yes that worked I changed it to this: 
<code>
$(document).ready(function() 
        { 
            $('div.structBody').addClass($('ul#ContentBreadCrumbsColor li').attr('class')); 
     } 
);  
</code>

Comment: Glad to help. When you're satisfied, just click the checkbox next to my response to accept this as the answer.